# linear model is unknown but dual variables are given

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Assume we have a linear optimization problem as below:

$$Min ~~z=c^Tx$$
Subject to:
$$A_{eq}x=b_{eq}$$
$$Ax \ge b$$
$$x \ge 0$$

Matrix $A_{eq}$ and $A$ are given, but  $c^T,~b_{eq}$ and $b$ are not available. Instead, we do know the actual values of the dual variables associated with the equality constraints. Is there a way to extract matrices $c^T,~b_{eq}$ and $b$ ? If this is not possible, what is the least information I still need to know to be able to extract $c^T,~b_{eq}$ and $b$ ? Would it help if I had the dual variables associated with the inequality constraints too?

I think I should be able to fill out the last snapshot of the simplex table using the information I know about the model, and then from there I might be able to obtain the unknown matrices, but haven't been able to do so.

Comment: If you have given specific values for matrices, then feel free to post them.

Comment: If we only know the dual variables for the first set of constraints, that's not enough information; in an extreme case, there are *no* equality constraints, and then we don't have any information about the dual solution.

Answer (score 0):

The optimality conditions are:
$c - A_{eq}^T \lambda_{eq} - A^T \lambda - \mu = 0$
$\lambda^T(Ax - b) = 0$
$\mu^T x = 0$
$\lambda \ge 0$, $\mu \ge 0$
where $\lambda_{eq}$ are the equality multipliers, $\lambda$ the inequality multipliers and $\mu$ the bound multipliers.

So depending on which information you have, you may be able to figure out the other quantities.